# Indeed scraper bs4, splitting parsed HTML code after grabbing it

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
url = 'https://fr.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20anlayst&l=france'

#grabbing page content and parsing it into html
def data_grabber(url):
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    job_soup = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"job_seen_beacon"})
    return job_soup


def job_title(url):
    titles = data_grabber(url)   
    for title in titles:
        t = title.find_all('tbody')
        return t
```

this is my source code, and im testing it out in jupyter notebook to make sure my functions work correctly but I've hit a small road block. My html soup from my first function works perfectly. It grabs all the info from indeed, especially the job_seen_beacon class.

Mr job_title function is wrong because it only outputs the first 'tbody' class it finds. [refer to image here, I don't have enough points on stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPeiE.png)

while for my data_grabber it returns every single job_seen_beacon. [If you were able to scroll, you would easily see the multiple job_seen_beacon's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdxgx.png)

I'm clearly missing something but I can't see it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

In moment you are `return` something from a `function` you leave it and that happens in first iteration.

Not sure where you will end up with your code, but you can do something like that:

```
def job_title(item):
    title = item.select_one('h2')
    return title.get_text('|',strip=True).split('|')[-1] if title else 'No Title'
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://fr.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20anlayst&l=france'

#grabbing page content and parsing it into html
def data_grabber(url):
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    job_soup = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"job_seen_beacon"})
    return job_soup


def job_title(item):
    title = item.select_one('h2')
    return title.get_text('|',strip=True).split('|')[-1] if title else 'No Title'

def job_location(item):
    location = item.select_one('div.companyLocation')
    return location.get_text(strip=True) if location else 'No Location'

data = []

for item in data_grabber(url):
    data.append({
        'title':job_title(item),
        'companyLocation':job_location(item)
    })

data
```

#### Output

```
[{'title': 'Chef de Projet Big Data H/F', 'companyLocation': 'Lyon (69)'},{'title': 'Chef de Projet Big Data F/H', 'companyLocation': 'Lyon 9e (69)'}]
```